# Filter SourceGear VaultWeb Checkins by user

Tags: version-control, sourcegear-vault

We're still using SourceGear Vault as VCS for some of our older projects.

Vault provides a html web interface called *VaultWeb* which enabled you to view the latest checkins, transactions and so on.

For example you can view a list of the most recent checkins via an uri like this:
http://sourcegear.service.foo.bar/VaultService/VaultWeb/RecentCheckins.aspx?repid=42&days=7

This lists all checkins in repository 42 (`repid=42`) within the last week (`days=7`).
What I'm wondering: is there any way to filter the result at a more detailed level?
At least I'd like to filter the checkins per user. So I thought appending a query parameter like `&username=alice` would do the trick. But this doesn't filter anything...

Does anybody have an idea?
I searched the web but didn't find anything helpful (list of parameters or something like that)...